# How to combine Recyclerview and Fragment?

Tags: java, android

I would like to combine a Recyclerview in an Activity that uses a TabLayout(Fragment), so that I can swipe between the different lists. However so far I only achieve to do either a ListActivity OR the tabbed activity (the standard one from android studio) but not both. Would be glad if someone could help on this.

**AdapterFish.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class AdapterFish extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<DataFish> data= Collections.emptyList();
    DataFish current;
    int currentPos=0;

    // create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
    public AdapterFish(Context context, List<DataFish> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }

    // Inflate the layout when viewholder created

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, parent,false);
        MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    // Bind data
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
        MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
        DataFish current=data.get(position);
        myHolder.textmatkul.setText(current.matkul);
        myHolder.textwaktu_batal.setText("Tanggal Batal: " + current.waktu_batal);
        myHolder.textwaktu_pengganti.setText("Tanggal Pengganti: " + current.waktu_pengganti);
        myHolder.textdosen.setText("Nama Dosen: " + current.dosen);
        myHolder.textruang.setText("Ruang: " + current.ruang);
        myHolder.textalasan.setText("Alasan: " + current.alasan);
    }

    // return total item from List
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textmatkul;
        TextView textwaktu_batal;
        TextView textwaktu_pengganti;
        TextView textdosen;
        TextView textruang;
        TextView textalasan;

        // create constructor to get widget reference
        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textmatkul= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textmatkul);
            textwaktu_batal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textwaktu_batal);
            textwaktu_pengganti = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textwaktu_pengganti);
            textdosen = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textdosen);
            textalasan = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textalasan);
            textruang = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textruang);
        }

    }
}
```

**Tab2.java** :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Lamberto on 03/04/2017.
 */

public class Tab2 extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use viewpager?

Answer (score 1):

**Try to follow below steps:**

1. Design your `activity_main.xml` with `Toolbar`, `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`
2. Design layout XML's with `RecyclerView` for your fragments that you want to show for each `Tab` content.
3. Use `FragmentPagerAdapter` to populate `Fragments` on `ViewPager`
4. Set `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `ViewPager` using `ViewPager.setAdapter(FragmentPagerAdapter)`
5. Use `TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(ViewPager)` to give ability to `ViewPager` to work with `TabLayout` functionalities.
6. For individual `Fragment`, create `RecyclerViewAdapter` to populate data to `RecyclerView`

Here is a simple [tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/12958/android-tablayout-viewpager). Hope this will help~

Comment: nothing to add ! An example following this steps can be found here: http://www.journaldev.com/12958/android-tablayout-viewpager